# Windows 10 - Looking for Explorer "Short by" Folder specific function

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I m curious, is there a setting in Win10 Explorer that you can "short by" a folder and all its subfolders at once? I looked around and check file explorer myself with no luck... Thank you in Advance for your time, Nick.

Comment: What does 'short by' mean?

Comment: Do you want to use shortened path name? Please clarify more details to help us understand your question better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows made it unclear how to perform this as there is indeed a hidden way to change it.

To change the default sort oder of all folders, all you need to do is the same as what you would normally do but with a little extra at the end.

1. Click your desired slot by type
2. Head to the Coloured `File` ribbon on the top bar
3. Select `Change folder and search options`
4. Now under the `View` tab there should be the `Apply to Folders` option

Ta-Da! Now whatever folder you wish to open will be slotted by the oder you chose a minute ago.

Comment: WOW! I knew it was an easy solution but as you said MS made it unclear. Thank you InfinitySL much appreciated!

Comment: Haha, no problemo